# ic_skip_previous_24dp.xml stretches on Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, vector-graphics

I added the `ic_skip_previous_24dp.xml` vector image from Android Studio 1.5 (Beta) via New > Vector Asset and the triangle stretches downward when rendering on 5.0 (works fine for 4.4 and 5.1, just an issue with API 21).

Here's how it renders on API 21 (5.0.1):

[image]

Here's how it renders on API 22 (5.1.1):

[image]

And here's the Android Vector XML that Android Studio imports:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M6,6h2v12H6zm3.5,6l8.5,6V6z"/>
</vector>
```

A couple notes:

- It renders the same way on a layout file in an `ImageView` (with or without the `scaleType` attribute).
- `ic_skip_next_24dp.xml` has no issues.
- I changed the color in the XML to white (from the default black) so that it's easier to look at, but the issue is identical on the unedited black version.

I know that I can get the icon as density-specific PNGs but I'd like to use the vector, if possible.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem. It looks like in certain devices it is not able to interpret "m" (relative move) in the generated pathData. Not sure why! Might be a bug.

Found out that if we change it to use absolute value "M" as shown below it works:
android:pathData="M6,6h2v12H6z**M9.5,12**l8.5,6V6z".

Adding the solution in the hope it will help others.